# How do i invoke a Restart method in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I was scripting the code for a simple 2d game it all went well until i tried to invoke a restart method for a a "GAME OVER" condition. In fact Unity prints error only in the Restart method

So far i've tried changing the name of the method, and typed the global class before the method. However, it stills shows "" before the Restart() method.

```
 using System.Collections;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using UnityEngine;
 using UnityEngine.SceneManagement; 

  public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
  {

bool GameHasEnded = false;

public float restartDelay = 1f;
public void GameOver()
  {
   if (GameHasEnded == false)
   {
        GameHasEnded = true; 
        Debug.Log("GAME OVER");
        invoke("Restart", "restartDelay");
   }
   } 
   }

 void Restart() 
  {
      SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name);    
  }
```

In Unity it shows the following error: Assets/Scripts/GameManager.cs(22,8): error CS0116: A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods

Comment: Your restart method needs to be inside the GameManager class, currently it is not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You've a typo `invoke` should be a capital `Invoke`

2) The second parameter of the function is not a string but a float, you're wrapping the variable in quotes making it a string.

Should be

```
Invoke("Restart", restartDelay);
```

3) As BugFinder mentioned, your function is outside the class, that's against the rules of C#
bring it back inside the class,

```
public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{

    bool GameHasEnded = false;

    public float restartDelay = 1f;
    public void GameOver()
    {
        if (GameHasEnded == false)
        {
            GameHasEnded = true;
            Debug.Log("GAME OVER");
            Invoke("Restart", restartDelay);
        }
    }
    void Restart()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name);
    }
}
```